# jQuery : Multiple Upload Files with text edit values

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to POST using jQuery Ajax.

It's work fine if i don't use files upload.

How i get the multiple data uploaded and send it to server ?

Is it possible to do this..?

Thank in ADvance.

**HTML :**

```
<form id="uploadimage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="text" name="rsdtIncdSourceID"  id="rsdtIncdSourceID" >
  <input type="text" name="rsdtTrnsId"  id="rsdtTrnsId" > 
  <input name="rsdtDescription" id="rsdtDescription" >
  <select name="rsdtMsrsId" id="rsdtMsrsId">
    <option></option>
  </select>
  <input type="file" id="input-file" required multiple>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-xl  wow fadeInUp" id="btnPost">Process</button>
```

**JS :**

```
 $(function(){ 


var $rsdtIncdSourceID   = $('#rsdtIncdSourceID');
var $rsdtTrnsId         = $('#rsdtTrnsId');
var $rsdtMsrsId         = $('#rsdtMsrsId');
var $rsdtDescription    = $('#rsdtDescription');
var $rsdtFiles          = $('#input-file'); **// HOW TO GET THIS VALUE ?**


$('#btnPost').on('click', function(){

    var match = {
        rsdtIncdSourceID: $rsdtIncdSourceID.val(),
        rsdtTrnsId: $rsdtTrnsId.val(),
        rsdtMsrsId: $rsdtMsrsId.val(),
        rsdtDescription: $rsdtDescription.val(),
        rsdtFiles: $rsdtFiles.files[0],  **// HOW TO add THIS VALUE ?**
    };

    $.ajax({
                type:'POST', 
                url:'http://xxxx:802/api/v1/transaction/matching/confirm',
                data: match,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var userObj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    alert($rsdtDescription.val());
                  },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                  }

    });

});

  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload?rq=1

Comment: well, i just need append it to FormData..